# How to make file description field as required?

Tags: 8, forms, files

I would like to set the file description as required.
I tried it with this code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'node_news_homepage_edit_form') {

    $form['field_downloads']['widget'][0]['description_field']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

But it didn't work.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: This seems to be the right approach, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216829/setting-a-field-on-an-entity-form-to-be-required, but the key `description_field` looks odd to me, did you check it exists in $form? Should be `description`, if it is named after the File field property and this is the field type the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community is working to solve this problem:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2320877

While this isn't the part of the Drupal core, you can do the following:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_news_homepage_edit_form') {
    $form['field_downloads']['widget'][0]['#process'][] = 'set_file_description_required';
  }
}

function set_file_description_required($element) {
    $element['description']['#required'] = TRUE;
    return $element;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.
Unfortunately the description field is just required after I saved the page. And if I have two downloads it just works for the first one.
But I will wait for the patch. Hope it would be soon available on drupal core.

Comment: It only works for the edit form because it checks for the edit_form id. I answered with a version that will work for any form and multivalued fields.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @DavidCzinege answer, a version that works for any form where the field appears and also for multivalued fields:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if (!empty($form['field_file']['widget'])) {

    foreach (Element::children($form['field_file']['widget']) as $el_index) {

      $form['field_file']['widget'][$el_index]['#process'][] = 'my_module_set_file_description_required';

  }

}

function my_module_set_file_description_required($element) {

  $element['description']['#required'] = TRUE;
  return $element;

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately I get an error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_module_set_file_description_required() (previously declared in...

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution Marc.